# django queryset with higher number of count

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    questions = models.ManyToManyField('Question', related_name="cat_question", blank=True)
    cat_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cat_description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.cat_name
```

Here what I want is I want to list top 7 categories which have maximum question count. For this I have done....

```
top_categories = Category.objects.annotate(q_count=Count('questions')).order_by('-q_count')[:7]
```

But its not showing what I want.. It is displaying the content normally no changes if there is category with high question count, it doesnot come on top.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you show how you're using top_categories in view and template?

Comment: can you give example of what data you are getting vs expected data. sorry but I have hard time understanding your problem

Comment: I just want my category which have maximum number of question to be in the top of the list and second maximum on second and so on... I am getting it in the way I have inserted the category in the database according to time

Comment: Seems to work for me with Django 1.6.3 on Postgres.